# How to add my application before launcher in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

How to modify boot sequence in AOSP: I will add custom application(registration app - login and password, which will be send to server for authorization purposes) before starting Launcher2 application. How can I do this? 
I know that ActivityManager manages which Activity to start, but I have no clue where should I place my application start. I need to launch my application right after android system boot complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ICS, there is a method named `startHomeActivityLocked` in `ActivityManagerService`. In that method, the `ActivityManagerService` will start the Launcher2 application by sending an `android.intent.category.HOME` intent.

```
boolean startHomeActivityLocked(int userId) {
    ....
    intent.setComponent(mTopComponent);
        if (mFactoryTest != SystemServer.FACTORY_TEST_LOW_LEVEL) {
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        }
        ActivityInfo aInfo =
            resolveActivityInfo(intent, STOCK_PM_FLAGS, userId);
        if (aInfo != null) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    aInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, aInfo.name));
            // Don't do this if the home app is currently being
            // instrumented.
            aInfo = new ActivityInfo(aInfo);
            aInfo.applicationInfo = getAppInfoForUser(aInfo.applicationInfo, userId);
            ProcessRecord app = getProcessRecordLocked(aInfo.processName,
                    aInfo.applicationInfo.uid);
            if (app == null || app.instrumentationClass == null) {
                intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mMainStack.startActivityLocked(null, intent, null, aInfo,
                        null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false, null);
            }
        }
}
```

So you can add your code in that method or before the call site of that method. In particular, you can replace the intent to make the `ActivityManagerService` start your application, not the Launcher. And when your application finishs the authentication, you can make your application send an intent to Launcher2.

In gingerbread, the method signature is `boolean startHomeActivityLocked()` because Android doesn't support multiple user in this build.

Comment: Is this the only way to launch an application on boot for AOSP? I would be interested if there are additional ways to do this.

Comment: Of course not, you can listen to the BOOT_COMPLETED event and start your application. @Shurane

Comment: @StarPinkER, Thank you, How can we chat privately here?